# How can I find users by field value?

Tags: plugin-development, relations

I have a field in my users of type user. This field holds a user's employer (another user).

How can I get a collection of all the employees in a plugin?

I tried `craft()->users->relatedTo($currentUser);` (where `$currentUser` is the employer) as that's pretty much how I'd do it in a template, but of course relatedTo isn't part of the usersService.

So how can I do this without just getting every user, checking their employer field and filtering out the matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ElementCriteriaModel` supports 'users' as well as 'entries'.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::User);
$criteria->relatedTo = array(
    'targetElement' => $currentUser,
    'field'         => $employer
);
$employees = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've used this technique loads of times, was having a major brainfart yesterday! Accepted as the answer.